# Unable to setup mod_jk Tomcat

Tags: java, ssl, tomcat, plesk, mod-jk

Server version: Apache Tomcat/8.5.54
OS= CentOS
Plesk Onyx 17.*

**How I configured:**
Installed Java & Tomcat from this [LINK](https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-centos-7)
Compiled mod_jk successfully

```
workers.properties
vi /etc/httpd/conf/workers.properties
worker.list=worker1
#define Node1
worker.worker1.port=8009
worker.worker1.host=localhost
worker.worker1.type=ajp13
worker.worker1.lbfactor=1
```

configured mod_jk.conf as:

```
vi /etc/httpd/conf.d/mod_jk.conf
<IfModule !mod_jk.c>
LoadModule jk_module "/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_jk.so"
</IfModule>
JkWorkersFile "/etc/httpd/conf/workers.properties"
JkShmFile "/var/log/httpd/mod_jk.shm"
JkLogFile "/var/log/httpd/mod_jk.log"
JkLogLevel info

#NameVirtualHost 163.152.24.189:80
<VirtualHost 163.152.24.189:80>
    ServerName  localhost
    JkMount /manager worker1
    JkMount /manager/* worker1

    JkMount /docs worker1
    JkMount /docs/* worker1

    JkMount /examples worker1
    JkMount /examples/* worker1

    JkMount /host-manager worker1
    JkMount /host-manager/* worker1

    JkMount /servlet/* worker1
    JkMount /*.jsp worker1
</VirtualHost>
```

mod_jk in $CATALINA_HOM/conf/ server.xml:

```
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="worker1">
```

mod_jk placement in domains vhosts directory (In case of Plesk):

```
vi /var/www/vhosts/system/hakim-group.com/conf/vhost.conf
<IfModule mod_jk.c>
JkMount /servlet/* worker1
JkMount /*.jsp worker1
</IfModule>
```

For all domains:

```
/usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/httpdmng --reconfigure-all
```

Tried to set SSL in Tomcat:

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias CABundle -file ca_bundle.crt -keystore /opt/tomcat/ssl/hakim_group.jks

keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias Certificate -file certificate.crt -keystore /opt/tomcat/ssl/hakim_group.jks

<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" keystoreFile="/opt/tomcat/ssl/hakim-group.jks" keystoreType="JKS" keystorePass="mypass"/>
<!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
```

**mod_jk log says**

```
   [Thu May 28 00:24:18 2020] [3024:140291324643456] [info] init_jk::mod_jk.c (3591): mod_jk/1.2.41 initialized
    [Thu May 28 00:24:18 2020] [3024:140291324643456] [info] init_jk::mod_jk.c (3591): mod_jk/1.2.41 initialized
```

**Tomcat log displays**

```
28-May-2020 00:31:21.028 WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement   No rules found matching 'Server/Service/Connector/Parameter'.
28-May-2020 00:31:21.033 WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement   No rules found matching 'Server/Service/Connector/Parameter'.
28-May-2020 00:31:21.034 WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement   No rules found matching 'Server/Service/Connector/Parameter'.
28-May-2020 00:31:21.034 WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement   No rules found matching 'Server/Service/Connector/Parameter'.
28-May-2020 00:31:21.034 WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement   No rules found matching 'Server/Service/Connector/Parameter'.
28-May-2020 00:31:21.035 WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement   No rules found matching 'Server/Service/Connector/Parameter'.
28-May-2020 00:31:21.185 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/8.5.54
28-May-2020 00:31:21.186 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Apr 3 2020 14:06:10 UTC
28-May-2020 00:31:21.186 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version number: 8.5.54.0
28-May-2020 00:31:21.186 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
28-May-2020 00:31:21.187 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            3.10.0-1127.8.2.el7.x86_64
28-May-2020 00:31:21.187 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
28-May-2020 00:31:21.187 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.252.b09-2.el7_8.x86_64/jre
28-May-2020 00:31:21.187 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_252-b09
28-May-2020 00:31:21.188 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
28-May-2020 00:31:21.188 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /opt/tomcat
28-May-2020 00:31:21.188 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /opt/tomcat
28-May-2020 00:31:21.189 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/tomcat/conf/logging.properties
28-May-2020 00:31:21.189 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
28-May-2020 00:31:21.189 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.awt.headless=true
28-May-2020 00:31:21.189 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom
28-May-2020 00:31:21.189 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
28-May-2020 00:31:21.196 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
28-May-2020 00:31:21.196 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027
28-May-2020 00:31:21.197 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xms512M
28-May-2020 00:31:21.197 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xmx1024M
28-May-2020 00:31:21.197 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -XX:+UseParallelGC
28-May-2020 00:31:21.197 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
28-May-2020 00:31:21.197 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/opt/tomcat
28-May-2020 00:31:21.198 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/opt/tomcat
28-May-2020 00:31:21.198 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/tomcat/temp
28-May-2020 00:31:21.198 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib]
28-May-2020 00:31:21.352 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-7070"]
28-May-2020 00:31:21.376 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
28-May-2020 00:31:21.407 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-auto-1"]
28-May-2020 00:31:21.408 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
28-May-2020 00:31:21.409 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-163.172.24.189-8009"]
28-May-2020 00:31:21.412 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
28-May-2020 00:31:21.413 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 1116 ms
28-May-2020 00:31:21.472 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
28-May-2020 00:31:21.472 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.54
28-May-2020 00:31:21.493 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/docs]
28-May-2020 00:31:21.973 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/docs] has finished in [480] ms
28-May-2020 00:31:21.973 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/host-manager]
28-May-2020 00:31:22.035 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/host-manager] has finished in [62] ms
28-May-2020 00:31:22.036 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/manager]
28-May-2020 00:31:22.081 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/manager] has finished in [44] ms
28-May-2020 00:31:22.081 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/examples]
28-May-2020 00:31:22.581 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/examples] has finished in [499] ms
28-May-2020 00:31:22.581 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/hakim-group]
28-May-2020 00:31:22.639 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
28-May-2020 00:31:22.648 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/hakim-group] has finished in [67] ms
28-May-2020 00:31:22.649 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/ROOT]
28-May-2020 00:31:22.678 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/ROOT] has finished in [29] ms
28-May-2020 00:31:22.766 INFO [hakim-group.com-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
28-May-2020 00:31:22.771 INFO [hakim-group.com-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/docs]
28-May-2020 00:31:22.800 INFO [hakim-group.com-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/docs] has finished in [29] ms
28-May-2020 00:31:22.800 INFO [hakim-group.com-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/host-manager]
28-May-2020 00:31:22.836 INFO [hakim-group.com-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/host-manager] has finished in [36] ms
28-May-2020 00:31:22.837 INFO [hakim-group.com-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/manager]
28-May-2020 00:31:22.875 INFO [hakim-group.com-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/manager] has finished in [37] ms
28-May-2020 00:31:22.875 INFO [hakim-group.com-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/examples]
28-May-2020 00:31:23.161 INFO [hakim-group.com-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: contextInitialized()
28-May-2020 00:31:23.162 INFO [hakim-group.com-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log SessionListener: contextInitialized()
28-May-2020 00:31:23.164 INFO [hakim-group.com-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: attributeAdded('StockTicker', 'async.Stockticker@68ae7efb')
28-May-2020 00:31:23.171 INFO [hakim-group.com-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/examples] has finished in [296] ms
28-May-2020 00:31:23.172 INFO [hakim-group.com-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/hakim-group]
28-May-2020 00:31:23.205 INFO [hakim-group.com-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
28-May-2020 00:31:23.210 INFO [hakim-group.com-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/hakim-group] has finished in [39] ms
28-May-2020 00:31:23.217 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-7070"]
28-May-2020 00:31:23.235 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Failed to start connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-auto-1]]
    org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: The connector cannot start since the specified port value of [-1] is invalid
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1076)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:440)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:766)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:688)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:343)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:474)
28-May-2020 00:31:23.238 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-163.172.24.189-8009"]
28-May-2020 00:31:23.242 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 1827 ms
```

when I access website as `**https**:// OR [**http**:]domain.com` Plesk displays `404 Not Found -- nginx` 
when I access [**HTTP**]domain.com:7070 then Tomcat working
when I send request as [**HTTPS**]domain.com:8443 then message says `This site can’t provide a secure connection`

Best regards

Comment: No configuration information provided, and off-topic.

Comment: @user207421 Thanks for your reply. I added all configuration information in my question. Please check